# How to set code indentation in comment in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, indentation

I am working on different projects, and people in different projects have different indentation preference. I wonder if I can use Emacs' mode line to set the indentation for each file. Any idea?

Comment: Which programming language(s) are your projects in?

Comment: mostly python and js

Comment: Both file-local and directory-local variables can resolve this. For a per-project basis, directory-local variables are usually best.

Comment: @phils, that's awesome and I find [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html) very helpful. However, it seems `dir-locals-set-directory-class` does not work over **sshx**. Any idea?

Comment: @davidshen84 Did you see the last two sentences of paragraph 2 in the documentation (the link you posted)? Did that not solve your ssh issue?

Comment: davidshen84: If you're running a version of Emacs prior to 24.3 then see http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DirectoryVariables for a workaround and example usage. With 24.3+ you can use the `enable-remote-dir-locals` variable (as Thomas points out).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*copy & paste @phlis' comments*

> Both file-local and directory-local variables can resolve this. For a per-project basis, directory-local variables are usually best.
>
> If you're running a version of Emacs prior to 24.3 then see emacswiki.org/emacs/DirectoryVariables for a workaround and example usage. With 24.3+ you can use the enable-remote-dir-locals variable (as Thomas points out).

Answer (score 0):

Another cross IDE option would be editorconfig. For example:

```
root = true

[*]
end_of_line = crlf
insert_final_newline = true
charset = gb18030
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2
```

Reference: http://editorconfig.org/